# Strongswan VPN certificate authentication failed

Tags: windows, vpn, certificate, ipsec, strongswan

I've installed strongswan vpn on my ubuntu server. Set up certificate authentication. I've set up my android-phone and it works fine. But connection didn't established on the windows machine. I copied ca-cert into root ca and client certificate into personal store. But I get an error 13806 (wrong certificate). What am i doing wrong?

/etc/ipsec.conf

```
config setup
        # strictcrlpolicy=yes
        uniqueids = no
        charondebug="ike 4"

include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc

conn %default
        dpdaction=clear
        dpddelay=35s
        dpdtimeout=300s

        fragmentation=yes
        rekey=no

        ike=aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp3072-modp2048-modp1024

        esp=aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp3072-modp2048-modp1024
        # left - local (server) side
        left=%any
        leftauth=pubkey
        leftcert=server.crt
        leftsendcert=always
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0,::/0

        # right - remote (client) side
        right=%any
        rightauth=pubkey
        rightsourceip=192.168.103.0/24,2002:25f7:7489:3::/112
        rightdns=8.8.8.8,2001:4860:4860::8888

conn ikev2-pubkey
        keyexchange=ikev2
        auto=add

conn ikev2-pubkey-osx
        also="ikev2-pubkey"
        leftid=ip_address_server
```

/etc/ipsec.secrets

```
: RSA server.key
```

server-cert

```
 subject:  "CN=domain_name"
  issuer:   "CN=IPsec CA"
  validity:  not before Apr 18 10:07:00 2022, ok
             not after  Apr 02 10:07:00 2025, ok (expires in 1079 days)
  serial:    a9:e3:a4:
  altNames:  ip_address_server
  flags:     serverAuth
  authkeyId: 13:f8:f0:
  subjkeyId: 5a:a8:11:
  pubkey:    RSA 2048 bits, has private key
```

client-cert

```
subject:  "CN=client"
  issuer:   "CN=IPsec CA"
  validity:  not before Apr 18 10:07:19 2022, ok
             not after  Apr 02 10:07:19 2025, ok (expires in 1079 days)
  serial:    4c:e2:46:09:81:87:14:60:96:79:cf:bb:d6:62:13:68
  altNames:  client
  flags:     clientAuth
```

and that's log

```
09[IKE] sending cert request for "CN=IPsec CA"
09[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ N(FRAG_SUP) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
09[NET] sending packet: from server_ip[500] to client_ip[500] (353 bytes)
07[NET] received packet: from client_ip[500] to server_ip[500] (40 bytes)
07[ENC] payload type NOTIFY was not encrypted
07[ENC] could not decrypt payloads
07[IKE] integrity check failed
07[IKE] INFORMATIONAL request with message ID 0 processing failed
```

As you can see I set ip address as SAN in server certificate, because connect over ip address. Dut it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you installed the certificates and key into the wrong keystore. For authentication via regular IKEv2 certificate authentication, you have to install them into the `Local Machine` store. The user-specific store is only used when authenticating via EAP-TLS (and only for the client certificate/key, the CA certificate still has to be installed in the `Local Machine` store).

Comment: No, I installed certificates into right store - Root CA into "trusted root certification authorities" of local computer, client certificate into personal store of local computer.
I think, maybe I made mistake in additional parameters certificate, like SAN, 
It is described in more detail [link](https://docs.strongswan.org/strongswan-docs/5.9/interop/windowsCertRequirements.html) here, but I do not understand what else I should specify besides SAN..